# Formula error in Excel - not returning desired value

Tags: excel, vba

why I get a

> "#NAME?"

in Range("AM5")

```
Range("AM5") = "=index(K5:K & LastRow,match(AK9,AK5:AK & LastRow,0))"
```

Comment: I know this code works if I don't use " & LastRow " !!

Comment: You're missing some quotes, as well as the `.Formula` after `Range("AM5")`: `Range("AM5").Formula = "=index(K5:K" & LastRow & ",match(AK9,AK5:AK" & LastRow & ",0))"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `worksheetFunction` object for writing formulas if you want the formula to be hidden:

```
Dim exFun As Object
Set exFun = Application.WorksheetFunction
Range("AM5") = exFun.Index(Range("K5:K" & lastRow), exFun.Match(Range("AK9"), Range("AK5:AK" & lastRow), 0)
```